# ion-back-button back to page A from C skipping B - ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

This back button takes me to page B from page C. But I want this to go back to A directly.

A -> B -> C

Actual back: B

Expected back: A

In another case: I want to take it to some other page X from C.

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
  <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `navigateByUrl` method of the Router in your component like this:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

navigateBackToPageA() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/route_A');
}
```

Comment: how can i use with ion-back-button?

Comment: Hi Ali, you can attach the method like this: `<ion-back-button (click)="navigateBackToPageA()"><ion-back-button>`

In the method, if you don't want to navigates without pushing a new state into history you should change the line I suggested to: `this.router.navigateByUrl('/route_A, { skipLocationChange: true })`

You can refer to the doc for more detail: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: Hi dev.doc, thank you for giving me the idea. I have used routerLink instead and it worked well on ion-back-button. :)

Comment: Glad to know that you found the answer. :)